# jpa criteria query fails after MapJoin

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria, criteria-api

I have the following `@Entities`

```
@Entity
public class Configuration{
   @OneToMany
   protected Map<String, Component> components;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Component{
    protected String displayName;
}
```

I do not understand why this works, returning all Configurations

```
  CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<Configuration> cq = cb.createQuery(Configuration.class);
  Root<Configuration> pc = cq.from(Configuration.class);
  cq.select(pc);
```

But if I do a MapJoin, even without setting any conditions, it does not return anything

```
  CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<Configuration> cq = cb.createQuery(Configuration.class);
  Root<Configuration> pc = cq.from(Configuration.class);
  MapJoin<Configuration, String, Component> mapJoin = pc.join(Configuration_.components); 
 cq.select(pc);
```

What am I missing? I'm at a loss, I've been through the tutorials, but have not found the answers I need. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the join type is inner by default, which means that for a configuration to be returned it has to at least have one component. If none of your configurations have a component, nothing is returned.

The first query is equivalent to

```
select configuration.* from configuration
```

And the second one is equivalent to

```
select configuration.* from configuration
inner join component on component.id = configuration.id
```